# Absolute (or relative?) path in PHP

Tags: php, path, include, relative-path, absolute-path

Sorry for asking it as it may be answered many times before, but my question is little bit different

I have tree like

```
/var/www/path/to/my/app/
   -- index.php
   -- b.php
   -- inc/
      -- include.php
```

(I'm accessing inc/include.php from index.php,

```
include "inc/include.php";
```

)

but in include.php, I need to get absolute path to APPLICATION root, not DOCUMENT_ROOT
so in result, I need to be able to use this command

```
//inc/include.php
include(APP_ROOT."/b.php");
```

repeating, I do NOT WANT TO CALL IT LIKE

```
include("../b.php");
```

is there native function, if possible?

## UPDATE:

I am wanting to get PATH by PHP as any open source need to have this path detection
why? If I would want to include inc/include.php from ajax/1/somethiing.php, it success but inc/include.php then tries to include ajax/b.php instead of b.php

## For Pekka:

I have this tree

```
-- index.php
-- b.php
-- inc/
    -- include.php
-- ajax/
    -- 1/
       -- ajax.php
```

Now look. From index.php, you'll call inc/include.php

```
include("inc/include.php"); //included file
```

now, included file searchs for

```
include("../b.php");
```

It will work, but! If I would call include of inc/include.php from ajax/1/ajax.php, like this

```
include("../../inc/include.php");
```

it will work, but included file will try to include

```
../b.php
```

instead of 
    ../../b.php as path is relative to file which INCLUDED that inc/include.php
Got it ?

Comment: There is no such PATH environment variable like you are looking for. All Open Source applications I know define this path in a central configuration file, *but you have to include that configuration file first, using a relative path*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there native function, if possible?

no. The document root is the only thing you can get from PHP. (Note however that in your scenario, you can simply call `include("b.php");` because the script is still in the context of index.php.)

**Re your update:**

You can define a global application root in a  central configuration file. Say you have `config.php` in your app root. Then do a

```
define("APP_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
```

you **still** have to include the config file, and you have to use relative paths for it,  e.g.

```
include ("../../../config.php");
```

but once you have done that, you can work relative to the app root inside the script:

```
include (APP_ROOT."/b.php");  <--  Will always return the correct path
```

Comment: But if I'm creating it for customer or as opensource, I can't know what path does he use

Comment: @genesis then you need to use relative paths (`../`), there shouldn't be any fundamental problems with them?

Comment: yes. When you are calling ../inc/include.php  from /ajax/1/something.php, include.php will try to include /ajax/some_file.php

Comment: @genesis then you need to include `../../inc/include.php`. What's the problem? Not sure I understand.

Comment: I'll describe it little bit more in my qeustion. Look above

Comment: Aah, didn't think about it. Thanks for an answer. +1, but wouldn't you mind to accept KingCrunch as he gave me, maybe easier answer and has less rep that you ?

Comment: @genesis sure, no problem at all. But I wouldn't use `getcwd()` for this. It's not 100% reliable (see the manual) and can be changed during runtime with `chdir()`

Comment: I am not planning to do so, but I finally decided to use your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: No. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php It's just disabled if you don't have full control over the server, but saying that you can only get things from the "document root" is wrong. That's a webserver thing, PHP doesn't care about your document root.

Comment: @phant0m what I am saying is that `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is the only "root path" variable that you can get via PHP by default. PHP does not know the concept of an "application root" directory - you have to take care of defining and finding it out yourself.

Comment: I'm not saying that, I'm saying that the include also takes into account the include path setting, which has no connection to `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: Note that `dirname(__FILE__)` will give something like `C:\wamp\www` on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve the path with the current file as the base

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/../b.php';
```

or since PHP5.3

```
include __DIR__ . \DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . '/../b.php';
```

Comment: Nice, but exactly what I did before

Comment: @genesis: No, it isn't. If you use `../b.php` PHP resolves the path relative to the current work directory (see `getcwd()`). The magic constant `__FILE__` always points to the file itself, thus `dirname(__FILE__)` points to the directory of the file. At the end `dirname(__FILE__) . $relativeToCurrentFile` will result in an absolut path. Just dump it and look at it yourself ;)

Comment: `echo dirname(__FILE__);` results in /var/www/path/to/app/inc oooh, getcwd() gave me  correct answer!

Comment: please edit your answer to `echo getcwd()."/b.php";` and I'll accept your answer

Comment: include getcwd()."/b.php"; makes no sense and is (almost) identical to include "b.php"; (except for some preset include paths)

Comment: @genesis Actually `getcwd() . "/b.php";` is a security risk, because with this it is possible to include malicious code: Because the current work directory may change, it is possible, that this string refers to a completely different file.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your index.php:

```
$GLOBALS['YOUR_CODE_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Add to your `inc/include.php`:

```
require_once $GLOBALS['YOUR_CODE_ROOT'].'/b.php';
```

Comment: it returns /var/www/path/to/my/app/inc - it'S not what I'm wanting to do

Comment: add the $GLOBALS declaration to your index.php before you call the include of subsequent scripts and add the require_once to your include.php

Comment: oh sorry. it works very well ! in inc/include.php I put `$path = dirname(__FILE__)."/../";include($path."b.php");` and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
define('APP_ROOT', 'your app root');
```

in index.php for example. Or in a config file.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't *define* your application's root path for you, it might be of interest to check out [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you only know the relative path, then you have to at least start with a relative path.  You could use [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to return the canonicalized absolute pathname, and then store that somewhere.

In your `index.php`, or a config file:

```
define(
    'INC',
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .
    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
    'inc' .
    DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
);
```

Elsewhere:

```
include(INC . 'include.php');
```

Alternatively, define a few constants for the different locations:

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('INC', DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'inc' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('AJAX', DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'ajax' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Elsewhere:

```
include(DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'b.php');
include(INC . 'include.php');
include(AJAX . 'ajax.php');
```